# Validations Cause Test To Fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following test:

```
    test "should get create" do
   sign_in(FactoryGirl.create(:user))
    assert_difference('Inquery.count') do
      post :create, FactoryGirl.build(:inquery)
    end
    assert_not_nil assigns(:inquery)
    assert_response :redirect
  end
```

and I keep getting:

```
 2) Error:
test_should_get_create(InqueriesControllerTest):
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken, License number has already been taken
```

What I don't understand is why I get this error in this particular test, when I have a very similar test:

```
 test "should get create" do
    sign_in(FactoryGirl.create(:user, admin: true))
    assert_difference('Event.count') do
      post :create, FactoryGirl.build(:event)
    end
    assert_not_nil assigns(:event)
    assert_response :success
  end
```

and this does just fine. The obvious difference is the admin: true line, but that has no effect as I suspected.

Added:

User_factory.rb

```
 factory :user do
   first_name "John"
   last_name "Doe"
   email "example@example.com"
   password "foobar"
   password_confirmation "foobar"
   license_number '12345'
   state 'AZ'
   specialty 'Neurosurgery'
  end
```

Comment: What order do the tests run in? What does the factory for User look like?

Comment: Added user factory. The tests run in the standard rails order: Index, Show, New, Edit...

Comment: You have a user already created with that email. Are there are any other user objects being created before this one that are persisting? Are you sure you're running in the test environment? Are you sure that the test environment is being cleaned out before each run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `User` is failing validations because your factory is setting up a new user for your test, but your database isn't being cleared in between. Change your factory to look like this, so that email and license_number are unique each time you create a `User`:

```
factory :user do
  first_name "John"
  last_name "Doe"
  sequence(:email) { |n| "example#{n}@example.com" }
  password "foobar"
  password_confirmation "foobar"
  sequence(:license_number) { |n| "12345#{n}" }
  state 'AZ'
  specialty 'Neurosurgery'
end
```